# Could ベビーカー be derived from "Baby carriage"?

Tags: etymology, loanwords, wasei-eigo, false-etymology

Most etymologies I've come across for "ベビーカー" assume that it's wasei eigo based on a combination of "baby" (ベビー) and "car" (the "カー" part of "マイカー"). For example, the Japanese edition of Wikipedia says this in a [footnote](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B9%B3%E6%AF%8D%E8%BB%8A#cite_note-1) on its article.

Could it instead be derived from a contraction of the English phrase "Baby carriage"? I suspect that "carriage" is distantly related to "car", for what it's worth.

Comment: Carriage and car are indeed from the same PIE root, but unless you have extremely compelling evidence for why it would come from carriage instead of the accepted etymology, I don't see why you think this.

Comment: In my experience, Japanese always tends to preserve phonetics over spelling when importing words and the first "a" in "carriage" is pronounced more like an え than an あ, contrary to the "a" in "car". E.g. the names "Cary"/"Carey" are typically transliterated as キャリー　or ケリー, not カリー.

Comment: yes, @bjorn, that's what's been bugging me, I couldn't put my finger on it! carriage in katakana is キャリッジ. Thank you! I knew something was off about the idea of カー coming from carriage but it wasn't coming to me.

Comment: I’d be careful assuming katakana loanwords (gairaigo) are from English. Many come from Dutch, German, or Portuguese and can be a bit different than their English cognates.

Comment: @bjorn A very large number of loanwords were borrowed via writing rather than directly via sound, so while I agree with you, I would suggest that in many cases the pronunciation that is represented is whatever pronunciation the Japanese speaker *imagined* the word having, fitting the patterns of existing loanwords they've already learned.

Comment: @snailboat I do not doubt that there are exceptions, but I cannot think of any. Do you have any?

Answer (score 5):

Several dictionaries (大辞林, 大辞泉, 明鏡, 日本大百科全書) list ベビーカー specifically as *wasei-eigo* from "baby" and "car", e.g.

> **ベビーカー** 〔<sup>和</sup> baby＋car〕

<sup>(I also checked 現代カタカナ語辞典 by 旺文社, but this doesn't have an entry for ベビーカー!)</sup>

Moreover, as @bjorn & @ericfromabeno say in the comments, "carriage" is usually キャリッジ and a loan of "baby carriage" would more likely have been something like ベビーキャリー.